# jQuery $(this) not selecting newly clicked button

Tags: jquery, wordpress, click, selector, this

I am using this code to insert the image source URL into relevant fields in WordPress's admin panel. This is part of my HTML structure for the form (repeats for every other field in that container) :
`

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">
    Label for input field 1 :
    </th>
    <td>
    <input class="upload_button" type="button" value="Upload" />
    <input type="text" name="upload" class="upload-url" value="Empty"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">
    </th>
    <td class="upload-preview">
    <img src="Empty" alt="Preview" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">
    Label for input field 2 :
    </th>
    <td>
    <input class="upload_button" type="button" value="Upload" />
    <input type="text" name="upload" class="upload-url" value="Empty"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row">
    </th>
    <td class="upload-preview">
    <img src="Empty" alt="Preview" />
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This is the Javascript code handling it :
`

```
var image_uploader;

jQuery("div#container").on('click', 'input.upload_button', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var formloc = jQuery(this).parent().parent();
    //If the uploader object has already been created, reopen the dialog
    if (image_uploader) {
        image_uploader.open();
        return;
    }

    //Extend the wp.media object
    image_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Use Image',
        button: {
            text: 'Use Image'
        },
        multiple: false
    });

    //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    image_uploader.on('select', function() {
        attachment = image_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        jQuery(formloc).next('tr').find('img').attr('src', attachment.url);
        jQuery(formloc).find('input.upload-url').val(attachment.url);

    });

    //Open the uploader dialog
    image_uploader.open();

});
```

I am using this structure to keep the form look neat (the preview of uploaded image appears below the input field). When a person has uploaded the image, the image URL should be inserted to the input field, as well as img src to show it immediately.

However, the **problem** is that this only works on the first click i.e. when I click on Upload Button 1, it works as intended but when I click on Upload button 2, the changes will still be reflected on the area which is supposed to be controlled by Upload Button 1. **It seems that $(this) only records the first clicked button and never changes thereafter.**

I would really appreciate your help to see what has gone wrong there. I have been cracking my head to find out the problem but to no avail. I'd be ready to provide more info should you need it.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Can you please upload HTML code for 2 input fields along with `<table>` tag?

Comment: @jcubic `jQuery(this).parent().parent();` is correct. Billy wants to select only `tr` tag. not `form` tag.

Comment: @MangeshParte the name of the var (formloc) confused me.

Comment: @MangeshParte : Added the `<table>` tag now. Thanks guys for checking the code.

Comment: Instead of jQuery(formloc).find('input.upload-url').val(attachment.url);, try using jQuery('input.upload-url', formloc).val(attachment.url); does it make any difference?

Comment: @AlejandroIvan : Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't make any difference. It seems the problem lies at the `if` condition as mentioned in the answer below. Still, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem is with `if(image_uploader)` condition. I think it is true the second time you click which makes it return instantly and the `on` event handler, that you hooked on last click, executes which has reference to first clicked item.

You should try and refactor the code.

Comment: `var formloc = jQuery(this).parent().parent();` is defined before the `if(image_uploader)` condition. So it seems like the problem is not with `if(image_uploader)` condition.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) This seems to be the problem. What I don't get is, why, as @MangeshParte said, that `formloc` was defined earlier than the `if` condition but it seems that it was 'skipped' when I clicked on another button and would still refer to the first clicked item? I thought whenever I `click`, the whole function should run in sequence?

Comment: Glad I could help. Well, `formloc` was defined earlier than the `if` condition but since the function returned from within if block, your `on` was never executed.